# jquery .html() does not work on ie8

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a jquery function which makes an ajax call to a webservice method on the web server, the method returns a html table with data. I am using .html() to render the return values on div. This works in Firefox,Chrome, Safari but does not work on IE8

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./../WebAjaxCalls.asmx/GetProductInstruction",
    data: "{'ProductID':'" + $("#txtProductID").val()  + "'}",
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.d[0] == "true") {
            **$("#dvProudctInstruction").html(data.d[1]);** 
        }
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function(e, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        bReturn = false;
    }
});
```

The line  **$("#dvProudctInstruction").html(data.d[1]);**  works on all browsers except IE8.

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

You could alert your response before assigning it html()

OR

You could use innerHTML property instead html() of jquery (though it's same)

And you might want to check [this](http://www.dottodotnet.com/2010/03/jquery-html-problems-in-internet.html) link

Comment: +1 for the link. worked in my case for issue with IE8 (the issue turned to be bad markup!). it says: _In IE it turns out that the jQuery .html() attribute won't replace contents of first matched element unless the new HTML is valid_

Answer (score 8):

It seems IE8 has problems inserting long strings of text with jQuery's html(), making the div's content just completely blank.
Just tried it with both a very long string and one containing just 'blah', and that made all the difference.

So if you're expecting very large chucks of text (like 2k+ characters), go for the native innerHTML.
Didn't do any further research, so I don't know what's the max length of a string to be passed through html() in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `data.d[1]` to a variable and then adding it?

For Example:

```
if (data.d[0] == "true") {
     var results = data.d[1];
     $("#dvProudctInstruction").html(results);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether its .html() that is not working or its something else, check it first. Put an alert and see if you get correct, expected html or not.

```
alert(data.d[1]);
$("#dvProudctInstruction").html(data.d[1]);
```

Most likely the html coming in data.d[1] contains error and IE is not able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a gut feeling, but are you sure that you enter the if-block at all? I am just asking having stumbled in true vs "true" a couple of times myself...

Try:

```
success: function(data) {
    alert('outside of if');
    if (data.d[0] == "true") {
        alert(data.d[1]);
        $("#dvProudctInstruction").html(data.d[1]);
    }
}
```

Might not be anything, but at least you would eliminate the possibility that you'd simply never run the code line you've highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

i have answered this problem on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823233/how-can-i-get-jquery-div-html-to-work-in-ie7/23853817#23853817)
you just need to change your code to be like this

```
$("#dvProudctInstruction").html(data.d[1].toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's bit of a late answer; but you could also fix it with a try/catch block. Sometimes you might not have all the control over the content.

This way you keep the original code working for the new browsers, while the catch runs the innerHTML for IE8.

```
try {
    //new browsers
    $('#dvProudctInstruction').html(data.d[1]);
} catch (e) {
    //IE8
    $('#dvProudctInstruction').innerHTML = data.d[1];
}
```

Hope this helps someone!