# jQuery: "Unexpected call to method or property access" in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I get that error whenever I press a certain button in my code and **removing the following line makes the error go away and the button work:**

```
$(selector_value_object).html(value_object);
```

And both my variables selector_value object and value_object are defined. In fact, that line only runs if both variables are defined. So what could be the cause of this error? IE8 should have support for .html(), right?

I run jQuery version 1.8.3.

Note: This problem only occurs in IE8.

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: Maybe just a string issue which IE8 doesn't handle, try: `$(selector_value_object).html($.trim(value_object));`

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105949/jquery-html-does-not-work-on-ie8) he had the same problem.

Comment: @A.Wolff That didn't help

Comment: So what is `value_object` value? Is it valid HTML string or what?

Comment: I had the same issue. Post your `value_object` here. I think the problem is that ...

Comment: It is possible that `selector_value_object` does not turn into a jquery element for some reason. If you put a breakpoint on that line and see what `$(selector_value_object)` is in the console, does it turn out to be an empty array?

Comment: What is the selector and what is being added in the value_object?

Comment: @A.Wolff: value_object in this case is exactly: "666000". Trimmed, no whitespace etc.

Comment: and `selector_value_object`?

Comment: @epascarello: The selector is an input field... And now I realise my mistake. I should have used val() and not html(). Strange it worked in other browsers..

Comment: @dfsq As I said, the selector was an input field. I solved it now. I used val() instead of html().

Comment: Here we go! Glad you solved it :)

Comment: please share the html line of the input field

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't know why you downvote instead of commenting. If there truly is reason for downvoting, please tell me so I learn something instead of just repeating the mistake in the future.

As for the solution: The problem was that I tried using html() on an input form field, which doesn't work in IE8. Using val() instead solved it.

Comment: It seems that when you are trying to work with a property that a element doesn't have, for instance setting a text on an image node `$('img').text('Hello');` you get this kind of error.